# Codeigniter undefined index while getting data from multiple ajax on page and submitting

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I am getting an

> undefined index error

What I am doing is taking data from ajax 3 times on main page and then trying to submit using standard procedure, but the text box I am  getting using ajax is showing in inspect element with the same name I am submitting. Please help.

Comment: show code & error messages

Comment: Unless you share your code, no one could tell you anything.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index